# Separate value that is inside a link

Tags: javascript, html, string, iframe

The value that all the links I place in the text bar is from this model:

Text bar:

```
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" style="width: 282px;" />
```

Link model:

```
https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita
```

The value I want to recover is the one between `OB_EV` and `/`, in this example the value would be:

```
21090572
```

This retrieved value, I want it to be used in `url.value` so when I click the button, the correct link is loaded in the `iframe`.

**How would the script look to be able to retrieve these values?

I have no knowledge of strings to separate these values.**

My current script:

```
            <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter">
               <button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 1</button>
               <input type="text" name="url" id="url" style="width: 282px;" />
            <iframe id="the-frame" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               (function () {
                "use strict";
                var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter'), url = document.getElementById('url'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame');
                url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + url.value;
                };
               }());
            </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String#slice` and `String#indexOf`.

```js
let s = "https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita";
let i = s.indexOf('OB_EV');
let res = s.slice(i + 5, s.indexOf('/', i));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Taking into account that the link will be placed in ```<input type="text" name="url" id="url" style="width: 282px;" />```, Could you demonstrate by value how it would look? Your model was what caught my attention the most, because of the ease of being able to change the search values if necessary!

Comment: @BrondbyIF Just use `let s = document.getElementById("url").value`.

Comment: Regarding the final link, it is correct to use this template ```the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + res;```?

Comment: It should be, but it depends on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

- Using the `split()` function.

```js
let link = "https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita";

//this would return -> 21090572/decic-vs-drita
let value = link.split("OB_EV")[1];

//this would return the real value -> 21090572
value = value.split("/")[0];

console.log(value);
```

More info at: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), specifically this pattern:

`^^https:\/\/sports\.hummerball\.com\/betting\/[\w-]+\/football\/OB_EV(\d+)\/`

[Try it out here:](https://regex101.com/r/7HVILs/1)

Usage:

```
const regexpObEv = /^https:\/\/sports\.hummerball\.com\/betting\/[\w-]+\/football\/OB_EV(\d+)\//;
const url = "https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita";
const match = url.match(regexpObEv);

console.log(match[1]);
```

Output:

```
21090572
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var url = 'https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita';
console.log(url.match(/OB_EV\d+/g)[0].replace('OB_EV', ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Matching and parsing digit values

```
  let string = "https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita"

  function parseNum(str) {
    str = str.match(/(\d+)/)[0]
    str = parseInt(str);
    return str;
  }
 
  console.log(parseNum(string))
```

**Solution 2**

Removing all digits  by simply replacing non-digits with empty string `' '`

```
  let string = "https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita"
    
  function parseNum(str) {
    str = str.replace(/^\D+/g, '');
    str = parseInt(str);
    return str
  }

 console.log(parseNum(string))
```

Comment: I don't love this approach because it seems brittle. There could be digits elsewhere in the url that are matched instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the pathname using [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) and capture 1 or more digits using `(\d+)` from OB_EV21090572/ in capture **group 1**.

```js
const url = new URL("https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita");
const m = url.pathname.match(/OB_EV(\d+)\//);
console.log(m[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is probably the way to go, but here is another explicit option.

```js
const s = 'https://sports.hummerball.com/betting/en-gb/football/OB_EV21090572/decic-vs-drita';

const x = s.split('/');

// Seems like your target would always be in the 6th of the array that #split returns.

const y = x[6];

// Since 'OB_EV' is 5 chars, we can slice at that position.

const val = y.slice(5, y.length);

console.log(val);
```